# .gitignore file for multiple Android projects under a master folder?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I am having a problem building a .gitignore file for my Android Studio workspace, this is my folder setup:

***Android Workspace***---
-> **School**/Application1, Application2, etc.,
-> **Projects**/Application1, Application2, etc.

Android Workspace is the master folder, School and Projects are used to organize my applications, They contain the folders created when I create a new Android Studio project.

I created a .gitignore file and placed it in Android Workspace, but it doesn't seem to be ignoring the files, I then tried placing two .gitignore files in each sub directory, but that didn't work either, so, my question is: How do I structure my .gitignore file to ignore the unnecessary Android Studio files from the Android Workspace folder no matter how deeply nested they are? Or do I have to place a .gitignore in each of the application's directory?

Thanks, and here's the .gitignore file I'm using (Generated by https://www.gitignore.io/):

```
### Android ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
/*/build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log
```

Comment: The gitignore needs to be at the root level of the git repo itself.

Comment: .git is in the master folder (Android Workspace) along with .gitignore, that folder is where I ran git config and set up the connection between my local repository and the GitHub repository.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [global `.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore) that will have the files/folders to be ignored in all git projects. For this, just run the following command

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

It will create a `.gitignore_global` file in your home folder that should have the files/folders to be ignored.

Comment: Does this upload a copy of the global file when you push?if not the disadvantage with this is that only your system will have the gitignore file, other copies of the repo won't.

Comment: Unless you have a repository for global configuration and use symbolic links, it will not be synchronized among all dev.

Comment: Would it work placing .gitignore_global in the Android Workspace folder instead of my Home folder? My other git projects are working fine, it's only this one that's having issues. If not I guess I could combine all the .gitignore files into this global one, but that would require a lot of deleting, commits, editing for repeats, etc.