# How to make sure .gitignore works for multiple Android projects in the same repository

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gitignore

My problem is similar to the one outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923160/gitignore-file-for-multiple-android-projects-under-a-master-folder/), but the solution did not help. I essentially have one Github repository with a whole bunch of different folders/directories that each contain a separate Android project.

The structure of one such project looks like  MyTeamRepo -> MyAndroidProject -> app

Normally if it was just a single Android project, throwing the .gitignore in the /gradle directory would work, but it's not working out in my case.

Here's what's currently in my .gitignore:

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
*.aab

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/caches


# Android Studio 3 in .gitignore file.
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
.idea/modules.xml

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following lines if you do not want to check your keystore files in.
#*.jks
#*.keystore

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild
# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json
# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md

# Version control
vcs.xml

# lint
lint/intermediates/
lint/generated/
lint/outputs/
lint/tmp/
lint/reports/
```

My problem is I still keep having these .idea and .gradle files popping up everywhere within the subfolders every time I make any changes to the Android project, causing all sorts of merge conflicts when I try to pull changes from Github.

I also think part of the problem is that the .idea had previously been committed to Github and now I am always tracking it.

What steps do I need to take to completely clean my repository and to make sure the .gitignore is doing its job?

Comment: delete .idea & .gradle folders and commit it on GitHub. so it will also delete from server. So next time it will not make any changes to commit

Comment: Did you read https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore ?

Comment: Why do you have multiple projects in a single git repo?

Comment: I've been thinking about separating the projects out too so it's less of a headache, but I'm working on a team at uni where we have a lot of small little modules and apps, and we divide the repos by semester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore a file anywhere in the tree use something like

```
**/.idea/modules.xml
```

and no matter where the `.idea` directory is that the `modules.xml` file will be ignored.

Comment: In my experience, `./idea/modules` is enough. `/folder/` bases at the root, `folder/` can be anywhere.

Comment: Noticed a typo in my comment though: `.idea/modules`, not `./idea/modules`